# Iterated conditional probability notation

Tags: measure-theory, definition, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, iterated-integrals

I'm currently self-studying Andrew Gelman's book "Bayesian Data Analysis" third edition. At the page 41, they write:

$E(\tilde{y}|y)=E(E(\tilde{y}|\theta,y)|y)$

I am ok with multiple conditions, and usually ok with the math involved in the book. But this notation with a nested condition confuses me. I tried to find a definition for nested conditions in past personal notes/books, but I did not find the definition. Online, I saw something similar in the "Tower property" there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties. But that page uses notation and concepts that the book does not use and that are a bit abstract.

I have a feeling that this is the definition I'm looking for:

$Pr[(A|B)|C]:=Pr[A|B,C]$ for events, or $E(E(x|z,y)|y):=E(E(x|z,y))=E(x|y)$ for iterated expectation of random variables.

Does someone have an online reference that defines nested conditions that confirms (or not) my feeling guessed definition? If I'm wrong, what would be the meaning of $Pr[(A|B)|C]$ ,and  $E(E(x|z,y)|y)$ (if any)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Expressions like $(A \mid B) \mid C$ are nonesensical. What they are doing behind scenes is to use the definitions of conditional densities and some cancellations and swaping of integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Mason, and @William M., and taking the time to review more in depths the law of total expectation, I found the source of my confusion : I was incorrectly using the law of total expectation.

The law of total expectation says $E[U]=E(E[U|Z])$, **but it also says that $U$ and $Z$ must be from the same probability space**. My mistake was to consider $U=(X|Y=y)$, add the condition with $Z$ ending up with $E[E(X|Z,Y=y)]$, and then I did not understand the necessity for the extra $|Y=y$. I was just adding a condition ignoring that the random variables were living in a restricted probability space. This was my mistake.

$E[X|Y=y]=E[E(X|Z,Y=y)|Y=y]$ is really a direct consequence of $E[U]=E(E[U|Z])$ but with the restriction that everything is happening in the probability space defined by the condition $Y=y$. We add the condition $Z$, but we remain in the probability space $|Y=y$. This is the meaning behind the extra $|Y=y$ I did not write at my first attempt.

$E[E(X|Z,Y=y)|Y=y]\ne E[E(X|Z,Y=y)]$ and I have a good example from the book of Bayesian statistics. In my original problem $E[E(\tilde{Y}|\theta ,Y)|Y]=E[\theta|Y]=\mu_1$ the posterior mean but $E[E(\tilde{Y}|\theta ,Y)]=E[\theta]=\mu_0$ the prior mean.

I don't think my digression on expectation written with subscripts is necessary anymore. So I removed it.

I hope that this answer will help if someone stumbles over the same difficulty!

PS:
I think it also clarifies the question about $(A|B)|C$.

Comment: You can actually view the identity as a case of law of total expectation: $$E(E(X \mid Z, Y) \mid Y = y) = E(E(X \mid Z, Y = y) \mid Y = y) = E(X \mid Y = y).$$ The last equality uses law of total expectation on the conditional measure given $Y = y$. Though law of total expectation is a special case of the tower property.

Comment: I believe your confusion arises from a delicate concept known as "regular conditional probabilities." In a nutshell, conditional expectations are defined only through the values of the integral and these does not define a function but an equivalence class of functions. This implies that tower properties inside conditionings have to be taken care of if one wants to be very nitty-gritty about it...

Comment: ... Regular conditional expectations essentially say that you have a member of the aforementioned class of functions that in fact behaves a.s. as one would intuitively expect and therefore, a.s. the operations you want to do hold for that particular member. This is how taking the conditional expectation inside another expectation is proven mathematically. To show that regular conditional probabilities exist is quite a fastidious task by the way and they don't exist always but they surely do exist in $\mathbf{R}^d$ (i.e. when conditioning on random vectors).

Comment: Another thing I feel forced to point out is that $X = A \mid B$ is _not_ an event. What you are really doing is the following: when $P(B) > 0$ you define a new measure $P_B(E) = P(E \cap B),$ however, this measure will not have total mass 1 but it will have total mass $P(B),$ so if you normalise by $P(B)$ you obtain a true probability measure. This shows succintly that $P(B) > 0$ is an _essential_ assumption. The measure so defined is denoted by $P(\cdot \mid B)$ and it is a probability measure on its own right....

Comment: In contrast, the expressions $P(\cdot \mid Y)$ are not probability measures but random variables. This again touches with regular conditional probabilities where one wants a version of $P(\cdot \mid Y)$ such that for almost every $\omega$ the value of $P(\cdot \mid Y)(\omega)$ is a true probability measure. The simplest case is to use densities and it avoids all the technical machinery needed otherwise.

Comment: @Mason, yes I agree since $E(E[X│Y=y,Z])=E(E[X│Y,Z]│Y=y)$ it's just that if I had naively tried to write it I would not have written it in the form $E(E[X│Y,Z]│Y=y)$. I guess it's the first time I see such an expression, so I did not naturally choose the conventional notation.

Comment: @Mason I think I am getting closer to my mistake/confusion. In your detailed law of expectation how come the $Z$ is inside? The law says that $E[U]=E(E[U|Z])$, so if you take $U=(X|Y=y)$, then we should get $E[X|Y=y]=E[U]=E(E[U|Z])=E(E[(X|Y=y)|Z])$? But for some reason I don't grasp right now, you wrote $E(E[(X|Z)|Y=y])$ instead. I think if you can clarify this it would help me!

Comment: @AlbertBeton I edited my answer to be a direct proof of this identity using conditional densities. I had to make the assumption that there is a joint density $f(x, y, z)$.

Comment: @Mason , thank you. I did some edits too. I think I finally get it.

Comment: @WilliamM. I think you pointed out something that helped when you reminded me of the new measure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$P((A \mid B) \mid C)$ does not make sense. But $E(E(X \mid Z, Y) \mid Y)$ makes sense. To parse it, first note that $E(X \mid Z, Y)$ is a random variable which is a function of $Z$ and $Y$. So we can write $E(X \mid Z, Y) = f(Z, Y)$. Now $f(Z, Y)$ is a random variable and $E(f(Z, Y) \mid Y)$ makes sense.

The equality $E(E(X \mid Z, Y) \mid Y) = E(X \mid Y)$ is a consequence of the abstract tower property. Some form of the tower property can be proven using conditional densities. You can prove this specific identity like this:
\begin{align}
E(X \mid Y = y) &= \int x f(x \mid y)\,dx \\
&= \int x \int f(z \mid y)f(x \mid y, z)\,dz\,dx \\
&= \int \int x f(x \mid y, z)\,dx f(z \mid y)\,dz \\
&= \int E(X \mid Y = y, Z = z) f(z \mid y)\,dz \\
&= E(E(X \mid Y = y, Z) \mid Y = y) \\
&= E(E(X \mid Y, Z) \mid Y = y).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped too.

Comment: The equation you wrote really does not prove the result, although it is otherwise appealing intuitively. The tower property states that $E(E(X \mid \mathscr{G})) = E(X).$ You can apply that to $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(Y)$ or $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(Z, Y)$ but you are applying it to $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(Z \mid Y = y)$ which is as nonesensical as $P((A \mid B) \mid C)$ is. Of couse, you mentioned "conditional densities" and that is the actual proof and it is given by me below. By the way, the result is true for "regular conditional probabilities" of which conditional densities is a particular case.

Comment: @WilliamM. Yeah the equations I wrote is the proof using regular conditional probability $P(Z \in dz \mid Y = y)$. The thing that follows from the tower property is $E(E(X \mid Z, Y) \mid Y) = E(X \mid Y)$ since $\sigma(Z, Y) \supset \sigma(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR THE SAKE OF EXPLANATION: I will denote with $t$ the sample points of the variate $\theta,$ $\tilde{\omega}$ those of $\tilde{y}$ and with $\omega$ those $y.$** Then, the random vector $(\theta, \tilde{y}, y)$ is assumed to have a density $f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, \omega)$
and that
$$
E(E(\tilde{y} \mid \theta, y) \mid y) = \int dt\ \left[ \int d\tilde{\omega}\ \tilde{\omega} f_{\tilde{y} \mid \theta, y}(\tilde{\omega} \mid t, y) \right] f_{\theta \mid y}(t \mid y)
$$
coincides with
$$
E(\tilde{y} \mid y) = \int d\tilde{\omega}\ \tilde{\omega} f_{\cdot, \tilde{y}, \mid y}(\tilde{\omega} \mid y),
$$
where $\cdot$ means that the variable "was integrated out and renormalised." By definition,
$$
f_{\cdot, \tilde{y}, \mid y}(\tilde{\omega} \mid y) = \dfrac{\int dt\ f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)}{\int d(t, \tilde{\omega})\ f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)},
$$
and
$$
f_{\tilde{y} \mid \theta, y}(\tilde{\omega} \mid t, y) f_{\theta \mid y}(t \mid y) = \dfrac{f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)}{\int d\tilde{\omega}\ f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)} \dfrac{\int d\tilde{\omega}\ f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)}{\int d(t, \tilde{\omega})\ f_{\theta, \tilde{y}, y}(t, \tilde{\omega}, y)}.
$$
Therefore, there is a cancellation and when you multiply by $\tilde{\omega}$ and integrate, you reach the same expressions. By the way, we have to assume that $|\theta| + |\tilde{y}| + |y|$ is an integrable random variable. (The same result applies for random vectors but we have to assume that their $\mathbf{L}^1$ norms are integrable.)